# no manifest. jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)

Tags: android, android-manifest, sign

When I sign my android app using `keytool`, it gives above mentioned error.

> no manifest. jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)

I have created keystore everything. What would be the reason? Any manifest error?

Comment: Is your app in 'apk' format? Can you post at least the signing command?

Comment: jarsigner -verbose -keystore myappkey.keystore
myapp.apk myappkey

Comment: also i am using mapview in my app..

Comment: Project->properties->Export unsigned package like that i am doing..

Comment: I can confirm that I also repeat exactly the two steps you have described and it works for me. It should be a problem with the tool versions. I am not totally up-to date. Is your jarsigner and ADT the latest?

Comment: I suppose you follow this instructions in generating the keystore? http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

Comment: yes..I use the same instructions as told in the developer site.

Answer (score 0):

I just received this same issue myself and it occurred when I tried to run

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
```

from outside of the directory of my ionic project.  When I ran it from the root of the ionic project, it worked.  Then I moved the signed apk to a different directory to run zipalign and publish to the Play store.