# Android jar is unsigned using valid keystore, needs SHA1 certificate?

Tags: android, android-studio, cryptography, digital-signature

I am attempting to generate a signed APK for my app. I'm using Android Studio to generate the release APK: build > generate signed APK. I then get a popup for my key store, alias, and passwords. This process has worked in the past but, I suspect, stopped working after a recent upgrade of tools and other support. What can I do to get Android Studio to generate the signed APK with a valid signature?

When I inspect the APK using jarsigner, from the Java 1.8 release, I get the message:

> jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)

If I use jarsigner to sign the app, it then installs on most devices but not on my device running Android 4.1. The command I used is:

```
jarsigner -verbose -keystore "...path...\perinote-release.keystore" app-release.apk perinote
```

Further, if I add to the jarsigner options:

> -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA

it is accepted by the Android 4.1 device. I found these options in another post, [no manifest. jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045119/no-manifest-jar-is-unsigned-signatures-missing-or-not-parsable), indicating that there was, at some point, a change in the encryption from SHA1 to SHA2.

Here is my build.gradle for "app"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'perinote'
            storeFile file('...path.../perinote-release.keystore')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.perinote.camera"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24

        renderscriptTargetApi 20
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

What can I do to configure Android Studio to use SHA1 so that my app(s) will continue to work on Android 4.1 devices? Or is there something else I should be doing?

**EDIT:** I realize I should switch to SHA256. But I still need a way for my app to run on Android 4.1. Do I need to generate two versions and publish both of them?

Comment: Try and always use top level tags as well (added android and cryptography) and make sure your tags are correct (signature should be digital-signature) or your Q will go unnoticed.

Comment: Thanks. Those are great suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get both signature versions, simply check the checkboxes for V1 and V2 at the bottom of the 2nd *Generate signed APK* dialog box.

I hadn't noticed this dialog changed after updating AS and blew right past it.